# How to use ActiveRecord's migration DSL in Rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake, database-migration

I need to perform some database manipulations, such as creating tables, adding indexes etc. I would like to use the same methods used in migrations, such as `create_table`, `add_index` etc. However, when I try this I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `add_index' for main:Object
```

I added this at the beginning of my file:

```
include ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements
```

However, now I get the following error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `allowed_index_name_length' for main:Object
```

This is defined in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::DatabaseLimits`. I tried to include `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters`, but it didn't include all subclasses/modules, as I expected.

So the question is - what should I do in order to be able to write the same code I am normally able to write within a migration?

Comment: Why are you doing that, by the way? Most "reusable migrations" exist in a form of rake tasks that install gem's migrations into a project to be run in the common migration workflow. Your approach seems to defeat the purpose of migrations in the first place.

Comment: @D-side I need to create some custom tables in the database, add indexes to them, populate them via stored procedures etc. What's more, I need to recreate them periodically and not once.

Comment: Ah, so that's runtime needs. Okay then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods in a migration are all class methods of the `ActiveRecord::Migration` class.  So you can call them like

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.add_index :foo, :bar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `ActiveRecord::Migration` directly:

```
>> f = ActiveRecord::Migration.new
>> f.connection.methods.grep(/^create/)
=> [:create_savepoint, :create, :create_database, :create_schema, :create_table, :create_join_table]
=> f.connection.methods.grep(/^add_index/)
=> [:add_index, :add_index_sort_order, :add_index_options]
=> f.connection.create_table(:awesome_table, force: true) do |t|
=>   t.string :foo  
=> end  
#> (44.0ms)  CREATE TABLE "awesome_table" ("id" serial primary key, "foo" character varying(255))
=> {}
```

Comment: Do I really need `connection`? It seems that `ActiveRecord::Migration.new` has the methods I need as well.

Comment: `connection`, just return the current db-connection `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` you can overwrite it, for another db at runtime. I prefer to use clear code.